# How to fix the build error ''Error signing output with public key from file '--Assembly.snk' -- File not found" on Azure devops?

Tags: .net, azure, build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to build a solution on Azure devops using a pipeline. The code in the solution is in C#, ASP.Net and has recently been migrated to Azure devops. When I run the build, I get the following error:

```
##[error]CSC(0,0): Error CS7027: Error signing output with public key from file 'CommerceSuite/eComObjects/IgnifyeCommerceAssembly.snk' -- File not found.
```

CommerceSuite is the name of the repository and eComObjects is the name of the folder where the snk file has been kept.

Below is the tag inside the csproj file for the solution where the path for the snk file has been specified.

```
<AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>CommerceSuite/eComObjects/IgnifyeCommerceAssembly.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
```

I have tried to put the snk file in various locations within the repository, but still got the same error. May be the way in which I am specifying the location is not correct. I am very new to Azure devops and I am still trying to figure things out. Please suggest what might be wrong.

Below is a screen shot of the folder structure.

[image: Folder Structure]

Answer (score 1):

> How to fix the build error ''Error signing output with public key from file '--Assembly.snk' — File not found" on Azure devops?

You do not need to specify the repository name `CommerceSuite` in the path for the snk file.

The path for the snk file should be like:

```
<AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>eComObjects/IgnifyeCommerceAssembly.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
```

**It should be a relative path based on your snk file and the .csproj file.**

That because there is a step **Get sources** in the pipeline, which we could specify the `Team project`, `Repository` and `Default branch`:

[image]

When the build is initialized, Azure Devops will copy the Repository to the agent. So, it is not related to the Repository, all the file just use the relative path based on project/solution folder.

In other words, if you can build your solution successfully on your local, then push the code to the repos. We do not need to change the path in the project/solution files, just select/specify the correct path in the build pipeline.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason it did not work when I had kept the path as 'eComObjects/IgnifyeCommerceAssembly.snk', but when I moved the snk file out and changed the path to simply 'IgnifyeCommerceAssembly.snk', it worked.

Comment: My project needs the files to be in sub-folders and not in the root folder. As of now things are working when the files being accessed are put in the root folder. I am still looking for the solution because things are not working when I put the files in sub-folders and try to access them using the path.

Comment: I have added the folder structure to my question, please let me know if you have any suggestions.